# OSX equivalent for reset

Tags: macos, terminal

On linux machines I used to type `reset` on terminal.

It was like, closing and reopening the terminal!
It is very convenient, because in debugging you wont mix error messages from previous executions.

The command does exists on OSX, however when i scroll up, the previous output is there too!

Comment: I have `/usr/bin/reset` in Lion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned, `reset` does work in OS X, however you can combine it with <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ alt/option</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to 'Clear Scrollback'. This clears Terminal's history scrollback.

Alternatively, you can just use <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to 'Clear All'. This works similarly to how you use `reset` in Linux.

Answer (score 3):

In OSX's Terminal.app, you can hit <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

This will clear your terminal session completely.

Also [see this](https://superuser.com/questions/122911/bash-reset-and-clear-commands)

Use the right tool for each job:

Use `clear` to clear the terminal window.

Use `reset` to reset your terminal when it gets messed up by control sequences.

Use `cat` only when you want to stream a whole lot of data from one place to another uninterrupted.